# Explanation for Exec call working in Unix

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

For my assignment, one of my question was explain Exec call. Below is my explanation, I was not given the mark. for this question i had actually read about it on few threads on stack-overflow. So, can someone explain where i am going wrong?

"When a child process calls an exec system call, exec discard all the current statuses and in the same current process space starts the new exec call as a new process."

Comment: It's not a new process.  It's the same process now running a new executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asked for definitions in formal contexts like exams, it is better to go with accepted definitions with references than make up our own.

From [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)):

> exec is a functionality of an operating system that runs an executable file in the context of an already existing process, replacing the previous executable. This act is also referred to as an overlay. It is especially important in Unix-like systems, although other operating systems implement it as well. **Since a new process is not created**, the original process identifier (PID) does not change, but the machine code, data, heap, and stack of the process are replaced by those of the new program.